# run cleartool findmerge on multiple files being read from a separate file in a loop

Tags: bash, clearcase

I'm trying to run `findmerge` in a loop to merge a specific set of files whose locations are stored in a text file. Something like below:

```bash
while read p; do
    cleartool findmerge $p -type f -fversion .../main/LATEST -merge
done < filesToBeMerged.txt
```

Here, `filesToBeMerged.txt` looks like below:

```
./MyProject/src/com/acme/AcmeManager.java
./MyProject/src/com/acme/AcmeLogger.java
./MyProject/build.xml
```

and so on.

However, when I run the above command, it only processes the "first" line from the file and then stops. What do I need to do so that this loops through all the lines in the file? Or would something like a Perl script be more suitable for this?

**EDIT:**
Adding bash version:

```
GNU bash, version 3.00.15(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

**EDIT 2:**
Adding bash script, `autoMerge.sh`:

```
f="./filesToBeMerged.txt"
fcontent=$(cat "${f}")

while read line; do
  echo "Starting to merge: ${line}"
  cleartool findmerge "${line}" -type f -fversion .../main/LATEST -merge
done <<< "${fcontent}"
#done < "${f}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually put the file in a variable first:

```
f="/full/path/to/filesToBeMerged.txt"

while read line; do
  echo "${line}"
done < "${f}"
```

You can also try the alternative

```
f="/full/path/to/filesToBeMerged.txt"

while read line; do
  echo "${line}"
done < <"$(cat ${f})"
```

or

```
fcontent=$(cat "${f}")

while read line; do
  echo "${line}"
done <<< "${fcontent}"
```

I prefer using variable with quotes and curly brackets: not `$p`, but **`"${p}"`**.

```
 cleartool findmerge "${p}" -type f -fversion .../main/LATEST -merge
```

Comment: Hey, @VonC. I tried both your approaches. The first one stops after processing the first line, just like my original approach. The second one throws the error `syntax error near unexpected token "<"\done < <"cat ${f}"`

Comment: @kodeninja what version of your bash are you using? As I am using in https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/sbin/check_diff#L92, try the second option with `done <<< "$(cat ${f})"`, or put the content of the file in a variable first, and try `done <<< "${aFilecontent}"`

Comment: @kodeninja I have detailed that last option in my answer.

Comment: Here's my Bash version: `GNU bash, version 3.00.15(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`. I updated my script as per your code as `fcontent=$(cat "${f}")

while read line; do
  echo "${line}"
  cleartool findmerge "${line}" -type f -fversion .../main/LATEST -merge
done <<< "${fcontent}"` but it still runs only once.

Answer (score 0):

Your original approach should work. Put `set -xo` in your script to perhaps see what's going on.